# Orgmode, How can I remove codeblock descriptions?

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I have an orgmode document with a latex codeblock:

```
    So:
    #+BEGIN_SRC latex 
    Hello
    #+END_SRC
```

But when I generate a pdf, I get:

[image]

How can I remove this "Latex" description, and have only "So: Hello" shown?
Thank you!

Comment: I exported the snippet above to latex/PDF and I got what you wanted, not what you got. I'd suggest that you try with a minimal init file that just loads org-mode appropriately but does not include any of your customizations. You might also try to check the generated TeX file and see if there are any strange packages included.

Comment: \lstset{language=latex,label= ,caption= ,captionpos=b,numbers=none} Was generated in latex. Can I give parameters with orgmode to modify this line?No weird packages included.

Comment: Ah, I see: I use minted, rather than listings: that explains the different behavior I think.

Comment: Even with listings, however, I get the right thing.  The TeX file contains `\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,label= ,caption= ,captionpos=b,numbers=none}
\begin{lstlisting}
Hello
\end{lstlisting}` and when it's processed to PDF, only the Hello is left.

Comment: What happens if you process the TeX file directly from the command line?

Comment: Probably `#+latex_header: \usepackage{listings}` has to be added.

Comment: @rvf0068: That should be present indeed one way or the other (see the doc for the variable `org-latex-listings` which suggests adding it to `org-latex-packages-alist`), but if it weren't there, the latex run would not produce a PDF at all: it should complain about the undefined \lstset. But maybe I''m being naive and that would solve it.

Comment: What is it your trying to do, what is in the init file for org and how do you trigger the export. There are a few things here which could be at play and we need to narrow them down to work out what is going on. Note that I don't see the same as you are. Try running emacs -q, loading the org package and then exporting to see if you see the same result - this will at least tell you if it is due to something in your init.

Comment: Thank you (all) for the replies. Thank you rvf0068. You solved it with: Probably #+latex_header: \usepackage{listings} has to be added. Thank you! Sometimes solving stuff like this costs hours!! :S <humble>In my case!</humble>

Comment: @Tim X  Now it looks as such :`(with-eval-after-load 'ox-latex
(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
      '("article"
  "\\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
                 \\usepackage*
      ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section{%s}")
      ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection{%s}")
      ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection{%s}")
      ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph{%s}")
      ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph{%s}")
)))

 `

Answer (score 0):

From the comment, I don't think that org-latex-classes is quite correct. In
particular, the \usepackage* bit doesn't look correct.

The C-h v for that variable states

```
Alist of LaTeX classes and associated header and structure.
If #+LATEX_CLASS is set in the buffer, use its value and the
associated information.  Here is the structure of each cell:

  (class-name
    header-string
    (numbered-section . unnumbered-section)
    ...)

The header string
-----------------

The HEADER-STRING is the header that will be inserted into the
LaTeX file.  It should contain the \documentclass macro, and
anything else that is needed for this setup.  To this header, the
following commands will be added:

- Calls to \usepackage for all packages mentioned in the
  variables ‘org-latex-default-packages-alist’ and
  ‘org-latex-packages-alist’.  Thus, your header definitions
  should avoid to also request these packages.

- Lines specified via "#+LATEX_HEADER:" and
  "#+LATEX_HEADER_EXTRA:" keywords.

If you need more control about the sequence in which the header
is built up, or if you want to exclude one of these building
blocks for a particular class, you can use the following
macro-like placeholders.

 [DEFAULT-PACKAGES]      \usepackage statements for default packages
 [NO-DEFAULT-PACKAGES]   do not include any of the default packages
 [PACKAGES]              \usepackage statements for packages
 [NO-PACKAGES]           do not include the packages
 [EXTRA]                 the stuff from #+LATEX_HEADER(_EXTRA)
 [NO-EXTRA]              do not include #+LATEX_HEADER(_EXTRA) stuff

So a header like

  \documentclass{article}
  [NO-DEFAULT-PACKAGES]
  [EXTRA]
  \providecommand{\alert}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
  [PACKAGES]

will omit the default packages, and will include the
#+LATEX_HEADER and #+LATEX_HEADER_EXTRA lines, then have a call
to \providecommand, and then place \usepackage commands based
on the content of ‘org-latex-packages-alist’.
```

So I don't think you should have that \packages* line in there. Also, you are
better off either using the custom interface to set this variable or put it as a
setq in your init file. I don't think there is any reason to have to load it
inside an eval-after-load call.

Use the org variables mentioned in the docs above to add/remove packages. You
need to be careful with this as I've found this to be one area org-mode can be a
little fragile - there are some package dependencies which kick in differently
depending on whether your exporting a whole org file as latex, part of a
file/tree or a block.